Почему ноль больше нуля?
Вот код:
    $value1 = 550;
    $value2 = 550;
    
    $dolg = $value1 - $value2;

    switch ($dolg) {
        case ($dolg > 0):
            print_r ( '<b>Долг клиента по оплате:</b> ' . $dolg . ' руб.' );
            break;

        case ($dolg < 0):
            print_r ( '<b>Переплата клиента:</b> ' . $dolg . ' руб.' );
            break;

        case ($dolg == 0):
            print_r ( '<b>Долг клиента отсутствует</b>' );
            break;

    }

Почему то срабатывает первый case и выводится "Долг клиента по оплате: 0 руб."
Хотя по моей задумке должно выводится "Долг клиента отсутствует".
Что я делаю не так? Спасибо заранее.
Версия PHP 7.4.33

switch ($dolg) -> switch (true). От вашего способа использовать switch волосы дыбом встают. И даже switch (true) не вполне традиционный способ. Используйте каскад if else.

В case ($dolg > 0) сначала производится вычисление выражения, а затем сравнение результата на равенство с агрументом switch. Вам нужен обычный if/else
if ($dolg > 0)
{
    print_r ( '<b>Долг клиента по оплате:</b> ' . $dolg . ' руб.' );
}
else if ($dolg < 0)
{
    print_r ( '<b>Переплата клиента:</b> ' . $dolg . ' руб.' );
}
else
{
    print_r ( '<b>Долг клиента отсутствует</b>' );
}

online compiler

Спасибо большое! Ваш вариант работает.

@179379 Вам стоило добавить свой ответ и упомянуть, что этот способ не будет работать у ОПа, так как match появился только в php8.

Да при чем здесь ваша ОПа? Это ПУБЛИЧНЫЙ ресурс, а не приватный чатик. Один ответ служит МНОГИМ пользователям. Этот вопрос просмотрело 43 человека, помимо вашей ОПы. Им всем полезно узнать, как пишут на РНР сейчас, а не как писали в прошлом веке
